# Why does a dead Elder Dragon kept spawning where ever I go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There was this Elder Dragon that kept spawning everytime I fast travel. The dragon is already dead, but I can't get its soul. Any answers?

Comment: Skyrim is glitchy. Do you have any DLC or mods isntalled?

Comment: @ColinD No DLC. I think its just a bug. – [Baws](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/54131/baws)